# Searching for uploading files Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking for plugin or gem for Rails 2 - to upload files.

I need:

1. progress bar
2. multiple uploading
3. work with database
4. Set image size (for example: thumb 200x200)
5. Set imgae size in MB (for example :maximum => 500.megabytes).

Anyone has any ideas? I looking for this gem/plugin for week :( and nothing... Can you please help me? VERY very THANK YOU!

Comment: I heard about this. Does it good?

Comment: yup it is! you should try it first

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either Carrierwave or Paperclip for handling the upload. Image resizing can be handled via both as post processes using ImageMagick etc.

For progress bars and multiple uploading have a look at www.uploadify.com

Few reference articles:

http://blog.assimov.net/post/4306595758/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and-carrierwave-on